# Add types for listener variables react-native typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a stateful class and I need to add a listener (specifically for the keyboard). In its current form, I get an error:

> TS2339 property keyboardDidShowListener doesn't exist on type 'Auth'

I would like to know where and what type of declaration I need to put in to stop the error.

Here's part of the code, let me know if you need more.

```
class Auth extends Component<Props, any> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow)
    }

   componentWillUnmount () {
       this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
   }
.....rest of class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be relevant way, to do it. You might want to correct typing of `keyboard event listener` to catch invalid code while linting.

```
class Auth extends Component<Props, any> {
    public keyboardDidShowListener: any

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow)
    }

   public componentWillUnmount () {
       this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
   }
.....rest of class
```